# What happened to WIL? Windows Interface Language?

Tags: windows, history

I have a book from 2009 in our Company language for the "Windows Interface Language." Limited information can also be found online here:

http://techsupt.winbatch.com/techsupt/PDFs/wil-lang20020712.pdf

This appears to have once been an effort from Microsoft to make something a bit like a batch script that handled windows; I assume that parts of it are used for programs like Autohotkey since I notice remarkable similaries.

Yet a google search for WIL finds no wiki reference and only extremely antiquated items. I haven't yet tried out the code in the 2009 book on my Windows 7, but I assume that it will still work.

Any history on this? What happened? What is it?

Comment: It is a product from Wilson WindowWare, it doesn't have anything to do with Microsoft.  It did not set the world on fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This appears to have once been an effort from Microsoft to make
>   something a bit like a batch script that handled windows

...no, Microsoft never developed such a thing, "WIL" is a proprietary (?) scripting language, requiring a custom "interpreter" (WinBatch.exe) which is - yet again - not developed nor even supported by microsoft. I think you need re-read your book.

Comment: Thank you, my apologies for my confusion. After some further research, I found information on WinBatch.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winbatch